# Required attribute "title" was not provided. for Install Promotion Campaign

Tags: ios, facebook, installation

I keep getting this error when trying to launch my iOS install ad campaign "Required attribute "title" was not provided."  Any idea what Title this is referencing?

Comment: What is this in reference to? Are you talking about some website?

Comment: Maddy he is referencing the Facebook ads for mobile apps. I am getting the same error

Comment: Yes, that's right.  I'm trying to promote an iOS app on the FB promotion network but keep getting that error message when I try and submit the campaign.